# Checking a website is accessible JQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use Javascript, to ping a website, and display a result from this.

I have set up this JSFiddle, but no luck so far. - https://jsfiddle.net/yyjowtru/

I feel this is really close, but it seems if I change the following code (the url), nothing seem's to change.

```
    // Check if we can see site
$.Ping("http://www.google.com").done(function (success, url, time, on) {
    // Insert an extra menu item linking to the sign-in page
    $("#menu-main-menu").append('<li><a target="_blank" href="#">Sign in</a></li>');
    // Change the width of an li to accommodate the extra menu item
    $(".navbar li").css("width", "14.2857%");
});
```

Can anyone see anything obvious?

Thanks in advance

EDIT
Screenshot of my JSFiddle
[image]

Comment: What else result other than "Sign in" showing you want to have? You want some message? Info about ms?

Comment: If you change the URL, even just to random letters, it still works?

Comment: No it doesn't. https://jsfiddle.net/yyjowtru/3/

Comment: Strange, it does for me, check OP{

Comment: Are other people seeing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well you forgot to load jQuery in the fiddle. Load it and it should work.
try this fiddle

`Frameworks & Extensions > choose jQuery version you want to load`

https://jsfiddle.net/yyjowtru/1/

Comment: Just changed this, I now have the issue I was meant to have.